# How to create a base58 encoding address of public key?

Tags: node, base58

Need to create a encoding address of public key. 
Is there any library file for create a encoding address?

Comment: In which language are you programming?

Comment: Is there any java script library?

Comment: Please search SE, this has been addressed. eztz.js is what you need.